# Using Ampere's circuital law for an infinitely long wire & wire of given length

Tags: electromagnetism

According to [Ampere's Ciruital Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law):

[image]

Now consider two straight wires, each carrying current `I`, one of infinite length and another of finite length `l`. If you need to find out magnetic field because of each, at a point (X) whose perpendicular distance from wire is  `d`.

You get magnetic field as $\frac{\mu I}{2 \pi d}$. Same for both.

But,

Magnetic field due to infinitely long wire is : $\frac{\mu I}{2 \pi d}$

Magnetic field due to wire of finite length `l` : $\frac{\mu I (\sin(P)+\sin(Q)) }{2 \pi d}$, where P & Q are the angles subtended at the point by the ends of the wire.

Why are we getting wrong value for using Ampere's circuit law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to notice here.

1. You can only make the assignment $\oint \mathbf{B} \cdot dl = 2 \pi d B(d)$ if the situation is radially symmetric.
2. In the case of a *finite* wire you either have charge building up at the ends or you have not specified the *whole* current distribution yet. Question: can you specify a radially symmetric return path and if so do you expected it make up the difference?

Comment: Regarding the finite case is it possible to get the B-field just at the finite end of a semi-infinite wire which extends to infinity only in one direction? I know I should take the charge accumulation at the finite end into account since it will generate a time-dependent E-field, hence a displacement current. Yet I am unaware of the mathematical details since the field of a point charge(assuming there is a point charge generated at the finite end of the wire) is not defined at the origin $r=0$. We need it in the integral to get the displacement current from the current density.

Comment: I suppose that for many cases you could assume that the wire ends on a small but finite-sized spherical capacitor, thus avoiding the need for a singularity. Then choose your surface to not intersect the capacitor.

Comment: Can you check my latest question on this site http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/182785/how-to-use-amperes-law-for-a-semi-infinite-wire-with-current

Comment: I had recently posted same question but slight variation showing symmetry by considering field at centre, i.e., $\alpha = \beta$