# Magnetic field due to long current carrying conductor at a point near its end

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

How can one show that the magnetic field due to an infinite long current carrying conductor (length a) at a point near its end is given by

$$B = \frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi a}$$

using Ampere's Circuital Law (preferably) or Boit Savart's Law?

Comment: Can you describe the geometry a little better, please? An infinitely long current carrying conductor doesn't have an end, and a conductor with an end can't carry a current.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Ampere's Law for a semi-infinite wire with current?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/182785/)